# How can I combine the color data (JPEG) and transparency data (PNG) of two separate Uint8Arrays?

Tags: javascript

Suppose I have a single original full RGBA image file which I have split in to two separate files.

A JPEG containing all image color data and a second PNG containing an alpha mask (transparency data).

I would like to be able to combine the images, applying the transparency data of the PNG to the color data of the JPEG in order to create what is essentially a new PNG.

I need to do this without the use of the canvas element.

Within a webworker I have retrieved both files as **arraybuffers**.

I can then loop through the data and if I so choose, build a base64 string representation of either image, which can then be transferred back to the main thread, or indeed, at least in firefox I can create an objectURL to make the transfer faster.

Looking at the simple code below:

```
var uInt8ArrayJPEG = new Uint8Array(jpegbuffer);
var uInt8ArrayPNG = new Uint8Array(pngbuffer);
var i = uInt8ArrayJPEG.length;
var output = new Array(i);

while (i--)
{
   /*
     Build new Binary array using the color data from 
     uInt8ArrayJPEG and transparency data from uInt8ArrayPNG 
     output[i] = ****something*****;

     To build a base64 string of either file I can simply do this instead:
     output[i] = String.fromCharCode(uInt8ArrayJPEG[i]);
     followed by a simple join('') outside the loop
   */
}
```

When I build a base64 string from either file, it is returned correctly from the webworker and the image is displayed in the browser.

This leads me to believe that I should be able to manipulate the data within the two Uint8Array's in order to build a new complete PNG file containing both the color information of the JPEG along with the transparency information of the PNG, and then send that through via one of the methods mentioned above.

Unfortunately this is where my understanding fails me.  Of course it is quite possible that I am completely off the mark and that this is not possible at all.  If that is the case please do not hesitate to say so.

How can I build a new array, or indeed a base64 string combining these two sets of data?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Interesting idea!  I've only heard of this being done on canvas elements previously.

Comment: @Brad Indeed, While Canvas is the obvious choice in this situation. I have come across a highly specific case where all processing absolutely has to be done off the main thread, meaning webworkers are my only choice. Overall rendering time does not matter too much, so if this is doable, it would be the perfect solution for my use case. Hopefully someone can help! :-)

Comment: @gordyr well it seems like you should be able to give the image data to a hidden `<canvas>` and then yank the data back in the four-byte-per-pixel canvas format pretty quickly.  You could then convert that to array buffers that you could hand over to the web worker (not via a  serialized copy, but via the "hand-off" thing that I can't remember much about at the moment).

Comment: You are going to need to use canvas at some point (or recreate the decompression of the jpg and/or png data streams to their RGBA bytes yourself). Once you do have both images accessible as RGBA bytes, you should be able to combine the Alpha channel values from the PNG file and the RGB channel values from the jpg file.

Comment: @Pointy You're absolutely correct.  Unfortunately in this case the combining of the images needs to be done completely without a canvas.  I need to somehow combine the raw data before it ever hits the main thread.

Comment: @JakeHeidt Ahhh thats interesting... I know that there are both JPEG and PNG decoders out there for javascript (jpgjs and pngjs respectively).  Is that where I'm going wrong then?  If I can decode the information of each first within the webworker, which I can do, how would I then go about combining the two decoded arrays?  Would it simply be a case of overwriting the alpha byte of the JPG then encoding it as base64?

Comment: @JakeHeidt If it is indeed the decoding that I was simply missing, please add your comment as an answer and I will mark it correct.  Once I have implemented the JS decoding I will update this question with a complete explanation of my solution... Cheers

Comment: Yes, and then you're going to need to re-encode the image as a PNG with alpha, unless you are ok in dealing with raw RGBA bitmap data. So you will need to basically decompress->combine->recompress for most use cases. There may be easier ways if you can use command line /server side tools to generate your output. If you absolutely must do this 'live' in javascript, this is going to be pretty cpu intensive for any 'large' images.

Comment: @gordyr well hopefully you can work it out. When you've got strange constraints like not being able to use a canvas - even a hidden one - it helps to explain exactly *why* you've got those constraints. Sometimes clever people will have ideas to get around those obstacles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are going to need to use canvas at some point (or recreate the decompression of the jpg and/or png data streams to their RGBA bytes yourself). Once you do have both images accessible as RGBA bytes, you should be able to combine the Alpha channel values from the PNG file and the RGB channel values from the jpg file.

Comment: Thanks, I'm working on it now, I feel kind of stupid for not realizing it was the decoding in the first place.  Regardless,  I know this is an extremely odd use case and for 90% of scenarios this would not be a viable solution.  At least not without the browsers exposing their own native decoders anyway.  But for what I need to do, it should be perfect.  Thanks again :)